# Can this Form be Regarded as an Intermediate Form of L'Hopital Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{{ln(\frac x{x+1})}}{\frac 1x} \tag 1$$

WolframAlpha regards this to be of intermediate form $\frac 00$ and goes to apply L'Hopitals' rule. What I see is though is a form of $\frac {ln(\frac \infty\infty)}0$.

I see that with some computations in the numerator we get:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {ln(\frac x{x+1})}= ln(\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\frac x{x+1}}) = ln(\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac {dx/dx}{d(x+1)/dx})=ln(\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} 1) =ln1 =0$$

So in fact the numerator equals to $0$. However if I replace in $(1)$ I get:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{{ln(\frac x{x+1})}}{\frac 1x} =\frac 0{\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac 1x} = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{0}{\frac 1x}$$

Which I don't see how I can solve. Applying L'Hopital repeatedly will always give to $\frac 00$. So what is the correct approach?

Comment: The numerator has limit zero. But you cannot *replace* the numerator by zero *before* applying L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  $\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$ when $x\neq 0$, replace $\ln\Big(\frac{x}{x+1}\Big)$ by $\ln\Big(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\Big)$ and then apply L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\quad\ln(\frac x{x+1})=-\ln(\frac{x+1}x)=-\ln(1+\frac 1x)$

Thus the limit is that same as $-\lim\limits_{u\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+u)}u\quad$ by setting $u=\frac 1x$.

Since $\ln(1+0)=\ln(1)=0$, this can also be seen as the derivative

$$\dfrac{\ln(1+u)-\ln(1)}{u-0}\to\bigg(\ln(1+u)\bigg)'_{[u=0]}=\bigg(\dfrac 1{1+u}\bigg)_{[u=0]}=1$$

Thus your initial limit is $-1$.